# How to do a switchmap or any better way to replace values in RxDart

Tags: dart, rxdart

I have a collection with chatroom information. Something like this:

```
{
  chatroomid: 59,
  members: [2,3]
}
```

Now what I want to do is, get the collection stream, in the course of doing that be able to replace the members string ids with a corresponding firestore document based on member id.

End result should look something like this:

```
{
chatroomid: 59,
members: [{
  id: 2,
  username: Johndoe1
},
{
  id: 3,
  username: Jennydoe1
}]
}
```

Is this possible with Dart RxDart?
Trying something like this fails:

```
  getChatroomStream(chatroomid)
  .switchMap((i) {
    return Stream.value(i.members.map((e) => i.members.add(Document(path: 'Global.userRef/$e').streamData())));
  })
  
  .listen((event) {print(event);});
```

> [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Concurrent
> modification during iteration: Instance of
> 'MappedListIterable<dynamic, void>'.
> #0      ListIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:337:7)

Answer (score 3):

```dart
class MemberInfo {
  final int id;
  final String? username;
  final bool isLoading;
}

class Room {
  final int chatroomid;
  final List<int> members;
}

class RoomWithMemberInfos {
  final int chatroomid;
  final List<MemberInfo> infos;

  factory RoomWithMemberInfos.initial(Room room) {
     return RoomWithMemberInfos(
       room.chatroomid,
       room.members
         .map((id) => MemberInfo(id, null, true))
         .toList(growable: false)
     );
  }

  RoomWithMemberInfos withInfo(MemberInfo info) {
      return RoomWithMemberInfos(
        chatroomid,
        infos
         .map((e) => e.id == info.id ? MemberInfo(e.id, info.name, false) : e)
         .toList(growable: false)
      );
  }
}

Stream<MemberInfo> getMemberInfo(int id) { ... }

getChatroomStream()
  .switchMap((Room room) {
      final initial = RoomWithMemberInfos.initial(room);
      return Stream
         .fromIterable(room.members)
         .flatMap(getMemberInfo)
         .scan<RoomWithMemberInfos>(
            (acc, info) => acc!.withInfo(info),
            initial,
         )
         .startWith(initial);
  });
```